# Is it safe to port forward to Flask development server?

Tags: python, flask, server, raspberry-pi, alexa-skills-kit

I am looking to control my raspberry pi using alexa voice commands and need to open up flask to accept incoming requests from outside my network.

My setup would have alexa using amazons AWS lambda to process the request and send a vocal response back to alexa. An aditional request would be made from the code hosted on AWS to my raspberry pi running flask.

My question is how safe would it be to publicly expose the flask server through port forwarding and what could I do to make this safe or safer?

I have read that changing the debug to False on flask would be advisable. Would it also be possible to set a rule in flask to only accept connections from specific domains?

Comment: No, it is not safe.  Use something like uwsgi and nginx to wrap it in.